# maven If mirror fails, fall back to original

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I have a sonatype-nexus configured in lan for maven and the is connected using the mirror configuration in settings.xml shown below.

```
<mirrors>
 <mirror>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>nexus.sb.karmalab.net</name>
  <url>http://<lan_repo>/remote-repos</url>
</mirror>
```

This setting creates an issue if the  is down. 
Is there some option to configure the mirror to connect to the remote repo id the local lookup fails.

Comment: i am not looking for such a configuration as mentioned in http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/If-mirror-fails-fall-back-to-original-td126735.html

Answer (score 0):

Maven Jira has [an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-714) for this feature, but it was closed years ago without being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar setup, where I have a Nexus3 Repository Manager setup on my lan, and ran into the same problem when I turned off my Nexus3 Repository Manager.

Based on what I read the issue linked by Igor Dvorhak was closed and the topic seems to not have been brought up recently.

Anyhow, here is a workaround that worked for me.

You get two locations to place settings.xml

1. User Level ... normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
2. Global level ... normally provided in ${maven.conf}/settings.xml.

If a User Level settings.xml is defined it takes precedence over Global level but also you can override it by giving the maven command the -s flag with the path to your settings.xml.

You can learn more about settings.xml here: [Maven - Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

So what I did is setup the mirror at the User Level, but when the repository the mirror is pointed at was down (i.e. our own setup lan repository), I instructed the mvn command to use the global settings.xml which is set to go to central by default.

I happened to have an environment variable called M2_HOME in my ${user.home}/.bashrc file when I was setting up apache maven, So I am going to reuse that environment variable to construct the path. Then there is a conf folder inside the apache maven installation folder that contains the global settings.xml.

Finally here is the command to workaround the offline mirror site.

`mvn clean install -s $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`

Note: Your paths may be different if your working on a Windows OS.